# Rails Papertrail Version Order Model by Changeset Diff

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

What's the cleanest way to order a model's versions by changeset?

I'm tracking an integer (consider amount of weight lost per week for example) and I want to show users who have ultimately "lost the most this week".

I've managed to hack the ugliest snippet you've ever seen together and I'm including it below.

I can't believe there's not some clever method for this. Any thoughts?

```
@scoreboard ||= PaperTrail::Version.where(item_type: "WorkoutLog").map do |version|
  if version.changeset['weight']
    first = version.changeset['weight'][0] 
    last  = version.changeset['weight'][1]

    next if first.nil? || last.nil?

    diff = last - first
    {diff: diff, id: version.item_id}
  end
end
```

Comment: is the weight change recorded once per week? or can there be multiple records per week where what you want is the diff between today and one week ago?

Comment: To rephrase, since you used weight change as an example, are you querying multiple changes over a certain period of time and trying to find the diff between now and then, or are you querying for one change over the time period? Can people enter this value more than once in a week?

Comment: @guiniveretoo although it may not be clear based on my snippet, time interval isn't important. for the sake of the example, consider it a weekly update, but all things being equal, I simply want to sort based on the changeset with latest version and the version before it. (i obviously have an `object_changes` column). make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Stop using PaperTrail as the main tracking system for the 'diff' - make it a first-class database object in your system. Then it gets a lot simpler to query the object for most lost:

```
DeltaWeight.where(created_at: 7.days.ago..Time.now).order(:amount_changed)
```

Or in the case where you only want to find the latest change for your related object:

```
DeltaWeight.order(:created_at).group(:user)
```

Comment: appreciate the input. unfortunately, i can't "stop" and change everything. ultimately Papertrail is rooted in an ecosystem bigger than this problem and works elegantly for several unrelated challenges.

Comment: I'm not saying stop using Papertrail... I'm saying stop using it to solve this problem.